# Localhosting in Visual Studio with IIS isn't using the .dll files from my .NET Website (I'm new to this)

Tags: asp.net, dll, nuget-package, visual-studio-2022, iis-express

**Some Background**
I recently inherited a large ASP .NET Visual Basic website (WSP). Unfortunately, I was unable to talk with the person previously working on it and now have a tight deadline. I know general VB code but am new to hosting.

The site itself is running on a server I can access, and updating files there is no problem. Before I update live files though, I'd like to test them locally.

TLDR: I'm brand new to testing ASP .NET projects locally

**My Main Issue**
The ASP .Net website project I inherited has a Bin folder with all the necessary dll files that seem to be from/are NuGet packages (Still learning here, sorry). When I run ISS Express in Visual Studio to localhost the project with Visual Studio (2022), I'm getting errors as if the packages are missing or not found, despite them being in the Bin folder already. How exactly do I get ISS Express/Visual Studio localhost to use the packages (in the form of dll files) in the Bin folder of the proj?

**What I Tried and More Context**

Before I fully understood that the dll files were connected to the packages I need, I did install some with the NuGet package manager, and that seemed to solve some problems but not all of them as I didn't have the full package list and was just going off the error messages I was getting and the assemblies in the web.config file for the project. While this does work, if the packages (and the right versions) are already in the Bin folder as dll files, I'd far rather use those!

I've also tried researching to find how I can point ISS/Visual Studio local hosting to the bin folder for packages, but ended up more confused than helped.

TLDR: The packages/dll files in the Bin folder are what I want, but I need help making sense out of how to get Visual Studio to localhost using those dll files

Comment: Back to the your very first sentence, do you know that's an ASP.NET Web Site project or an ASP.NET Web Application project? If not, then no further discussion can be meaningful. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project/ Well, I have to be honest to say that the more you tried on the wrong path the more pains the process can offer. Hire an experienced consultant if you can, and I don't expect you can teach yourself two decades of ASP.NET evolution in a short period of time. Don't ask others to guess as we cannot see the code this way.

Comment: @LexLi Sorry for the poor vocabulary I honestly wasn't aware the two existed (WSP and WAP) but I've confirmed the project is a WSP and I'll correct the original question. Unfortunately I can't hire a consultant nor am I trying to learn everything, only a few changes need to be made to keep the site current until we can move to a more modern solution.

I was hoping for a point in the right direction on what my problem is, or someone to clarify that I actually do just need the NuGet packages locally as well as the dll files in the Bin, without trying to learn two decades worth. Any info helps!

Comment: You _are_ going to need a consultant if you don't have the time to learn, there's just too many unknowns that we can't ask about without triggering some mod flag because of excessive comments. Yes, DLLs are delivered as NuGet packages, but a project should already come with a list of packages it requires to be compiled (packages.config considering a WSP, in newer projects they're only mentioned in the .csproj). You don't _install_ packages to fix compiler errors, you _restore_ them. IIS, or rather the .NET runtime, _does_ use DLLs presentin the bin folder. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you much! I was starting to look into restoring the packages but was a bit lost. Correct me if my new understanding is wrong, but packages are more than DLL files and need to be on your local machine or the server as well? And restoring them is essentially re-pulling all the files you need locally? I'm researching now <i>how</i> to restore and what all that entails. If my understanding is correct and it's rather straight forward to restore from a packages.config (Which I've found! The root is quite messy and I missed it first go) any info there would be helpful, thanks again!